# How should I properly malloc an array of struct?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


HANDLE wHnd;    // Handle to write to the console.
HANDLE rHnd;    // Handle to read from the console.


struct Terra {
    int status;
    CHAR_INFO display;

};
int main(){
    int countX = 0;
    int countY = 0;
    int total = 0;
    CHAR_INFO ScreenCon[10000];
    int localcount = 0;

    struct Terra *world= malloc(10000*sizeof(*world));
...
```

I have been using visual studio programing a screen console program that generate and display an 100 x 100 CHAR_INFO array. without using *malloc()*. My code is referenced from [Ben Ryves' windows console tutorial](http://benryves.com/tutorials/winconsole/).

The code without *malloc()* function is:

```
struct Terra world[100][100];
```

This code works perfectly but the compiler warns me that I should allocate memory for it. So I tried to integrated memory allocation in it and I learned that *malloc()* can't allocate 2d array directly, I can only do so by dividing my chunk of memory into 100 parts and use 1 extra array to store their location, my solution is to revert that 2d array into 1d and handle the data location with extra code. However, with reference to other question in stack overflow, I have change my code to the one above. But I got error code E0144 and C2440 at line 28, what have I done wrong?

**Isn't that code is supposed to created a new pointer of struct Terra who called world then allocate 10000 x the size of single Terra is for it?** How should I initialize an pointer before its declared??

I have read some information about *malloc()* but seem I don't understand how this really work. I would like to know what I have done wrong.

P.S.: I have done more tests and it seems the problem is that *malloc()* statement:

```
struct Terra {
    int status;
    CHAR_INFO display;
};
int main()
{
    struct Terra* world = malloc(10000 * sizeof(*world));
    return 0;
}
```

This code also returns the same error.

Comment: The original code is a 2D array but the `malloc` you have shown is for a 1D array. Is that intentional? And please show a complete code example including exact error msgs with line numbers.

Comment: you want to allocate it for `CHAR_INFO display;` only , not for entire struct, right?, also can you show what is `CHAR_INFO`

Comment: If you remove `CHAR_INFO ScreenCon[10000];` (and related usage), still get errors `E0144` and `C 2440`?

Comment: The initialization of `world` works fine. The problem is in something else. This allocation indeed allocates space for 10000 `Terra`s behind the pointer `world` and there is nothing in this code that suggests you're initializing a pointer before it is declared. [Here it is compiling](https://godbolt.org/z/57E1ba). And please take a moment to think about the difference between allocating `100*100` `Terra`s at once in one chunk of memory, and allocating 100 chunks of 100 `Terra`s in different parts of memory and getting another chunk of memory to tell you where the other chunks are.

Comment: `malloc(10000*sizeof(*world));` is good, but it is just the first step.  More info needed for a good answer.  Consider a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry for the misleading info, first of all, i do want to allocate memory for whole struct. And those error both appear at line 28. '''CHAR_INFO  ScreenCon[10000] '''is not related to the error. It is that my understanding the console accept 1d array, as a result, i have to transfer the information in world (an 2d array) to 1d array for display. i also need to allocate memory for it.

Comment: And it seems the problem is located at that line of code, a program that only contain the struct and `struct Terra *world= malloc(10000*sizeof(*world));` still return the same error, should i change for other complier??

Comment: "This code work perfectly but complier warn me that I should allocate memory for it. " That seems doubtful. Please provide that warning/error you got there. Actually please review all of the question for consistence. I suspect that with the edits you made according to  feedbacks, some things got inconsistent. Be careful however, if you would change the question away from the answers you got it would not be appreciated. In that case please create a new question instead.

Comment: It is the message that complier give me when i simply create an 100x100 array.

Warning C6262 Function uses '120048' bytes of stack:  exceeds /analyze:stacksize '16384'.  Consider moving some data to heap.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to have the equivalent of `struct Terra world[100][100];`, but allocated with `malloc` rather than having it on the stack, right?

I assume you know that you can allocate hundred objects of type `foo` like this:

```
foo *bar = malloc(100* sizeof(*bar));
```

`bar` is now a pointer to the first element of an array of 100 `foo`.

So in the `world` 2d array above you have an array of arrays of `struct Terra` of length 100. Basically, `foo` is an array of 100 `struct world`:

```
typedef struct Terra foo[100];
```

You can now allocate 100 of those arrays:

```
foo *world =  malloc(100* sizeof(*world));
```

World now points to the first array of 100 `struct Terra` of 100 such arrays

Naturally, this can be done without a `typedef`:

```
struct Terra (*world)[100] =  malloc(100* sizeof(*world));
```

I know this text may be a confusing mess of "arrays of arrays" but I hope you get the point.

Just an added comment on using `malloc`. When doing allocations like this: `malloc(count * sizeof(*something))`, be sure to make sure that the multiplication doesn't overflow. One of the biggest security bugs in the java virtual machine, was a failure to do such a check.

Answer (score -2):

#### Correct/Valid solution:

If you want to access/iterate the 2D array like it got declared like `struct Terra world[100][100];`

Then you can alloc 100 diferent arrays, like this, and

```
struct Terra **world= malloc(100*sizeof(Terra*));
for(int i=0; i<100;i++){
    world[i] = malloc(100*sizeof(Terra));
}

//the "usual" way to access the indexes
for(int i=0; i<100;i++)
    for(int j=0; j<100;j++)
        printf("%d ", world[i][j].status);
```

But if you want to use a singles continuous chunk o memory, you must allocate it like a 1D array, and access it doing some simple math:

```
size_t total_size = 100*100  //100 and 100 are the dimensions
struct Terra *world= malloc(total_size*sizeof(Terra));

//this way to access the indexes
for(int i=0; i<100;i++){
    for(int j=0; j<100;j++){
        //the formula to convert 2D indexes to a 1D array is: (i*N)+j, where N = number_of_columns
        printf("%d ", world[i*100 + j].status); 
    }
}
```

### wrong old answer

```
struct Terra **world= malloc(100*100*sizeof(Terra));
```

Comment: This is most *definitely* not it. If you wanted to get `struct Terra **world` then you'd have to allocate space for 100 pointers, then loop over this space and allocate 100 `Terra`s each for each pointer.

Comment: You're 100% right, sorry i was sleepy.

I will leave this comment for educational purposes. And delete it after some days (2 or 3)